# What does this output from SelectKBest mean?

Tags: feature-selection, scikit-learn

I am using selectKBest from ScikitLearn.  I am getting this kind of output with mutual_info_regression.

> Y Column: someYColumn, Predictors: ['predi.1', 'predj', 'predk',
>   'predk.1', 'predk.2']

What does this mean?  Looking at theses columns, they don't form any correlation on an individual basis with someYColumn.

Edit:
I am interested in the following:  Why are some predictors coming up twice, three times?  What is the .n beside the predictor?  What does that number mean?

Edit:
It looks like I had columns with the same name, so selectkbest has just enumerated them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP commented with a solution that is not of general use.

Answer (score 1):

Correlation measures only linear relationships. Mutual information can measure non-linear relationships. For example, suppose $X \sim \text{Uniform}(-1, 1)$ and $Y = X^2 + \epsilon$. The correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is zero, yet the mutual information can be high. `SelectKBest` ranks all features according to its `score_func` parameter - mutual information in your case - and, well, selects the $k$ best features.

This is only useful as a preprocessing step before applying a non-linear classification algorithm such as a tree-based model or a neural network. If you are planning to use a linear model, such as logistic regression, then using `SelectKBest` with mutual information would be a serious error as it might include features the linear model could not use and throw away features that it could use!

Even for non-linear models, considering MI for each feature in isolation is a very poor way to do variable selection. While it detects non-linear effects, it considers each variable one at at a time and does not consider interactions between features. A feature which may have little value on its own can have considerable value when intersected with another. For that reason, I don't recommend *any* univariate variable selection technique, including `SelectKBest`, except for quick-and-dirty exploratory analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the extra numbers are an enumeration of columns that have the same name.